# What do I need to learn in order to repair an ogv or ogg video that is defective? Where to start?

Tags: video, encoding

I recorded a video chat session with recordmydesktop in linux, but it is somehow defective. I give more details in a (big) footnote down here. I badly need to repair and play that video.

Please put me in the right direction, what should I learn about, which internet sites provide that information, and any clue on what you should thing the problem could be. I don't shy away from doing any learning efforts, but the question of Video Production is just too wide. Any help on narrowing the search for the probable cause would be very helpful.

---

This is the capture of the konsole during the recording:

> inma:~> recordmydesktop
>
> Initial recording window is set to:
>
> X:0   Y:0    Width:1366    Height:768
>
> Adjusted recording window is set to:
>
> X:6   Y:0    Width:1354    Height:768
>
> Your window manager appears to be KWin
>
> Initializing...
>
> Buffer size adjusted to 4096 from 4096 frames.
>
> Opened PCM device default
>
> Recording on device default is set to:
>
> 1 channels at 22050Hz
>
> Capturing!
>
> ^CShutting down.
>
> ---
>
> Cached 72482 MB, from 215345 MB that were received.
>
> Average cache compression ratio: 66.3 %
>
> ---
>
> Saved 54287 frames in a total of 54245 requests
>
> ....
>
> STATE:ENCODING
>
> Encoding started!
>
> This may take several minutes.
>
> Pressing Ctrl-C will cancel the procedure (resuming will not be
>   possible, but any portion of the video, which is already encoded won't
>   be deleted).
>
> Please wait...
>
> Output file: out.ogv
>
> [89%]   [Cache File 141]
>
> Encoding finished!
>
> Wait a moment please...
>
> Done.
>
> Written 921301705 bytes
>
> (885658169 of which were video data and 35643536 audio data)
>
> Cleanning up cache...
>
> Done!!!
>
> Goodbye!

But now I try to play the file:

> inma:~> mplayer out.ogv
>
> MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer
>   Team
>
> mplayer: could not connect to socket
>
> mplayer: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote
>   control.
>
> Playing out.ogv.
>
> libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)
>
> Mismatching header version 53.19.0
>
> libavformat file format detected.
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed
>
> Ogg : Warning found none bos page from unknown stream 1091944242
>
> libavformat file format detected.
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> [ogg @ 0x2b4a70f82940]Codec not found
>
> LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed
>
> Exiting... (End of file)

What is happeing with this recording? Will

Comment: none of those messages indicate anything is wrong with the recording.

Comment: where you able to repair the .ogv file ? I have the same problem.

Comment: @dark 
 
I wasn't. But I learnt how to avoid it in further occasions. This is the point: you need to plan ahead before using recordmydesktop and have at least 100 GB free in your hard disk for a ~30 minute video. With less than that, recordmydesktop will exhaust the available space during the recording with temporal files, and the result will be a defective video with no warnings or error messages. The program is pretty fragile: be careful too not to activate desktop effects or anything similar while using it or you get a segmentation fault and the recording will be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you do not have the necessary codec to play the video in mplayer. You will need to find a codec that can decode it. I can't tell from the posted information what codec it is.

Comment: It is not a codec issue. I can play videos recorded in identical circumstances after AND before that one.